# My Error: useNewUrlParser has no effect since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next major version

Tags: reactjs, node.js, database, mongodb, react-fullstack

I am using mongoose to connect the MongoDB with my backend.

`const connectDB = async () => { try { const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, });`

This is the piece of code I wrote and it has 2 warning: "Warning: useNewUrlParser is a deprecated option" and "Warning: useUnifiedTopology is a deprecated option". Is there a way to fix them?

I tried installing version <4.0 but same error is picking up.

Comment: Stop using it? Plenty of results, including in official documentation, for that warning text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve this mongodb Warning issue in node js and How to traceback about errors in nodeJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77415433/how-to-resolve-this-mongodb-warning-issue-in-node-js-and-how-to-traceback-about)

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove it. Your code should look like this

```js
  const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
      const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be resolved by updating the MongoDB connection setup in Mongoose to use the latest default settings. Simply connect without specifying any additional options:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {});
        console.log("CONNECTED TO DATABASE SUCCESSFULLY");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('COULD NOT CONNECT TO DATABASE:', error.message);
    }
};
```

#mdmahfuzrp #mahfuzrp #mrp