# I'm having troubling in connecting to MongoDB when I'm using modules

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb

This is my index.js file(working fine) where I am connecting to database.

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

const DB = process.env.URI;
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

const connect = mongoose.connect(DB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
  console.log("Connection successful");
}).catch((err) => console.error("Connection failed", err));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

But when I am writing the connection code in another file and try to import it as a module, it's giving an error.

This is my conn.js file:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const DB = process.env.URI;
console.log('DB:', process.env.URI);

const connect = mongoose.connect(DB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
  console.log("Connection successful");
}).catch((err) => console.error("Connection failed", err));

export default connect;
```

This is index.js file where I am getting an error:

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT
const DB = process.env.URI;
import connect from "./db/conn"

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

Error:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:40
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/kshitijgupta/WEB D/mern-estate/server/db/conn' imported from /Users/kshitijgupta/WEB D/mern-estate/server/index.js
Did you mean to import ../db/conn.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:233:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:845:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1043:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  url: 'file:///Users/kshitijgupta/WEB%20D/mern-estate/server/db/conn',
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I am also attaching snippet of my directory for better understanding:[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaAvi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code that you need to fix and I will explain why.

Firstly, when using ES Modules the [docs say](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions) that:

> A file extension must be provided when using the import keyword to resolve relative or absolute specifiers. Directory indexes (e.g. './startup/index.js') must also be fully specified.

That means you need to change this:

```js
import connect from "./db/conn"
```

to this:

```js
import connect from "./db/conn.js" //< Note the .js file extension
```

Secondly, when using the `dotenv` package with ES Modules there is a certain way you need to import the package, as you can see from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv?activeTab=readme). This has to do with the differences in the way you export modules in CommonJS to ES Modules and whether or not your `.env` variables will be in scope when you use them.

For you than means you need to change this:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
const app = express();
dotenv.config();
```

to this:

```js
import 'dotenv/config'
const app = express();
```

Lastly, as you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77420202/21972629) the `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology` are no longer valid options so you should modify your connection to this:

```js
const connect = mongoose.connect(DB).then(() => {
  console.log("Connection successful");
}).catch((err) => console.error("Connection failed", err));
```